# ESP8266 Find MAC address access point

Tags: c, wifi, esp8266, mac-address, bssid

I want to find the MAC address of the network access point im connected to. Then i would like it print the MAC address in the serial monitor.
What i´ve tried so far is the following:

```
#include <"WiFi.h">
const char* ssid = "NetworkSSID"
const char* pass = "NetworkPASS"

void setup(){
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_MODE_AP);
  Serial.println(WiFi.softAPmacAddress());
```

My problem is whenever i run this code i get an error saying mode is not defined, not sure how to get around it.

If anyone has a solution or knows what could be the problem it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: From which documentation did you get that `WiFi` has a `mode` method?

Comment: There is no WiFi.h header file for the ESP8266. Please edit the question to copy into it the text of the actual, complete error message(s).